# image.onload return is not my wanted

Tags: javascript

I used the canvas tag to crop my image.

as following my code:

```
autoCropImage(url){
    var img = new Image();
    const cropApp = this;

let x = img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const center_X = img.width/2, center_Y = img.height/2;
    let init_X=0, init_Y=0;
    ctx.drawImage(img, init_X, init_Y, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
let dataUrl_short = dataUrl.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
return dataUrl;
}();



img.src=url;
console.log(x);
return x;

}
//log result:
//data:,
```

I consider the log result should be a string of base64, but the callback is  `data:,`

What's the problem in my code?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: if I declare the variable `let result = 'hello world` in the `img.onload` function and `return result` `console.log(x)` will be hello world

Comment: @Oscar um... In fact, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Than learn how to use it https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: I use the inspect to see the console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). You are calling it **immediately** and then assigning its return value to `img.onload`.

(Then you assign the value of `img.onload` to `x`).

This means that you are not assigning a function to `img.onload`, so nothing happens after the image loads.

It also means that the image hasn't loaded when you try to pass it as an argument to `ctx.drawImage`.

Since the image hasn't loaded, there is no data to convert to a data URL with `canvas.toDataURL`.

---

You need to:

1. Remove the `()` from after the function definition so it gets assigned to `img.onload` and called *when the image loads*
2. Get rid of `let x =` because that will just be a copy of the function
3. Read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: how can I call the function when the image loaded?
use the async function?

Comment: @ChamperWu — See item 1 in my list of things you need to do.

Comment: You mean using `img.load = function(){...}` to instead of  `let x = img.load = function(){}();` right? but I do it, and `console.log(img.onlaod)` will callback a function

Comment: like this `ƒ () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var center_X = img.width / 2,
            center_Y = img.height / 2;
        var init_X …`

Comment: I want to return a base64 string

Comment: You can't wait for the image to load and return a string. See item 3 in my list of things you need to do.

Comment: I tried this `async autoCropImage(url){
...
img.onload = function(){
...
return dataUrl;
}
let x = await img.load;
console.log(x);
};` and return is undefined

Comment: @ChamperWu — If you use `await`, then you have to await a function declared with `async` (you don't). A function declared with `await` has to return a Promise (you haven't created any Promises).

Comment: In my experience, I used the async function when I use the method of ajax. the code will be `imgPost(url){return axios.post("url")} async dataCallback(file){let response = await imgurPost(file);
    const result = response.data.data;
    const link = result.link;
    return link}`

Comment: `img.onload` is not a Promise object, but it's an asynchronous function. Is there a good way to let me get the value of dataUrl?

Comment: See the question linked to in step 3. It has many examples of how to turn an callback into a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to return the data url without the `data:image/jpeg;base64` part?

If so you're returning `dataUrl` instead of `dataUrl_short` in the method.